# How to give users an individual instance of an app?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have made an app within a Django project that is basically a message board. I have also made full login feature, everything there is working properly. When a user logs in, they go to /username/app/, a view that displays all messages . However, they all end up on the same message board with the same messages on it. What I want is for every user to have their own instance of this message board isolated from all other users. How can I implement this? I feel like there is something obvious that I am missing. I looked at stuff like this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to. If anyone could point me to some resources for understanding this problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create a relationship between User and Messages, then run a query that will find all messages referenced in User. This can be done with sessions. Once the user is logged in, he will have a session open (individual instance) and you can customize the template there.